# Is it possible to overwrite the response data in a Mojo::Message::Response?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

In a Mojolicious app I have a route in my Controller code like the following:

```
/account/:id/users
```

The /account/:id part of the route has the following data in it when I get to the 
users part of the chain:

```
$VAR1 = { 
    'signup_ip' => '172.17.5.146', 
    'z_id' => '382C58D8-529E-11E1-BDFB-A44585CCC763', 
    'signup_date' => '2012-03-12T12:11:10Z', 
    'name' => 'Some Cool Account Name', 
    'users' => [ 
        { 
            'user_id' => '382C67EC-529E-11E1-BDFB-A44585CCC763' 
        } 
    ], 
    'account_id' => '382C67EC-529E-11E1-BDFB-A44585CCC763',
};
```

In the users part of the chain I'm getting the above hash using
$self->tx->res->content->get_body_chunk(0)

```
sub users { 
    my $self = shift; 
    my $user_list = from_json( $self->tx->res->content->get_body_chunk(0) );    
    $self->respond_to( json => $user_list->{users} );
}
```

The problem I'm having is that I want to overwrite the response with only
the users arrayref.  The code above in sub users(){} doesn't do that.  That is,
when I dump the result in the test, I still getting the entire hash.
The $user_list is the arrayref I'm looking for in users() but I'm unable to overwrite it.

Anyone have an idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hrm I think I put my previous answer in the wrong place. So here it is:

In the application I added the following routes:

```
my $base = $r->bridge('/account/:id')->to('account#read');
$base->route('/')->via('get')->to('account#index');
$base->route('/users')->via('get')->to('account#users');
```

In Acount.pm

```
sub read {
    my $self = shift;
    # do stuff

    $self->stash->{account} = $data;   # set the stash

    return 1;     #return 1.  Don't render.
}

sub index {
    my $self = shift;
    my $data = $self->stash('account');  #get the stash 

     $self->render_json( $data );
}

sub users {
    my $self = shift;
    # do stuff

    my $data = $self->stash('account');
    $self->render_json( $data );
}
```

Doing this sets the result of /account/:id into the stash in the read sub.
Setting a route to $base->route('/')->via('get')->to('account#index');
causes calls to /account/:id to be rendered from the index sub.

The route $base->route('/users')->via('get')->to('account#users') causes
the calls to /account/:id/users to be rendered from the users sub.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to provide different parameters to `respond_to` method. I would expect this to work:

```
$self->respond_to(json => { json => $user_list->{users} });
```

Or just call `render_json`:

```
$self->render_json($user_list->{users});
```

**Edit:** I made simple testing script that works for me (using latter option above):

```
use Mojolicious::Lite;

get '/account/users' => sub {
    my $self = shift;
    my $user_list = {
        'signup_ip'   => '172.17.5.146',
        'z_id'        => '382C58D8-529E-11E1-BDFB-A44585CCC763',
        'signup_date' => '2012-03-12T12:11:10Z',
        'name'        => 'Some Cool Account Name',
        'users' => [{'user_id' => '382C67EC-529E-11E1-BDFB-A44585CCC763'}],
        'account_id' => '382C67EC-529E-11E1-BDFB-A44585CCC763',
    };
    $self->render_json($user_list->{users});
};

app->start;
```

the request to http://localhost:3000/account/users returned this:

```
[{"user_id":"382C67EC-529E-11E1-BDFB-A44585CCC763"}]
```

Comment: I tried both of these without success.   It seems like this ought to be easy. Unless I'm thinking about this incorrectly, this seems like it would be a common action. The action being /account/:id/users and extracting a list of users from an account and returning those.

Comment: @jmcneirney - I made simple testing script (see updated answer) - it looks correct. Are you sure you have proper data in `$user_list` during the route processing?

Comment: Thanks.  That's a little different then my problem though.  I've got 2 different routes.  /account/:id  and /users.  Someone on IRC gave me the idea to stash in /account/:id  rather than render.  I'm still working on that.  So, sub read() == /account/:id.  The route goes there and needs to stash the outcome and from there sub users == /users is called.  Which needs to render a sub set.

Comment: So what I ended up doing was have a sub read() in the Account controller, ($base = $r->bridge('/account/:id)->to(account#read)), that sets the stash and returns 1. Then have another route $base->route('/')->via('get')->to('account#index');   The idea being that account#read sets the stash and never renders. Whenever /account/:id is called index() actually renders the data. With  /account/:id/users,  the users() sub gets its info from the stash and renders it.

Comment: Please add what you actually did as an answer and accept that.